# How can I deactivate bad RAM regions on a Macbook Pro (Retina 13")?

Tags: memory

Is there a way to deactivate bad RAM regions on a Macbook Pro Retina 13"?

I was not able to update my Mac to OS X 10.10.3. Complete reinstall was also not successful. I ran diagnostics and memtest86, both revealing bad regions of RAM. **What can I do other than repairing the Macbook?** I don't have an APP so repairing would be very expensive.

Comment: Linux supports doing this in a few different ways, broadly referred to as "BadRAM support". See for example [How to blacklist a correct bad RAM sector according to MemTest86+ error indication?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/75059/2465) (note that the linked question is about Linux, not OS X). Maybe OS X has something similar? The *proper* course of action would be to replace the RAM stick itself with a functional one.

Comment: It's possible that you would get better answers to this on our Apple-specific site, [apple.se]. You can "flag" your question for moderator attention and request migration if you want it moved there instead. *Do not simply repost the question on another Stack Exchange site.*

Comment: Thank you very much for your input and your corrections. I read blacklisting bad sector on linux which gave my the idea that something similar might be possible on OS X. I am still learning my way around hear but stackexchange can be quite strict.

Comment: You're doing fine for a new user so far. The question is quite okay. (Generally speaking, if you are having trouble putting into English words what you want, then focus on being specific and worry less about grammar and word choice. Not to say those are unimportant, but those are *fixable*.) Now that you have enough reputation to [participate on meta](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/participate-in-meta), if you have any questions about how the site itself works or what is on-topic, then post those over on [meta] and we'll most likely be happy to help you out.

Comment: OS X doesn't feature this sort of functionality out of the box, and as your Mac is a Retina model it will have its DRAM soldered onto the logic board rather than being socketed. Having said that, it's always worth getting in touch with Apple support, several times if necessary. In our experience Apple support can be quite inconsistent, and where one person may say "No AppleCare? Sorry you'll have to pay for a repair" someone else may well be more sympathetic and offer a free repair for an issue that was possibly there from day one - it's happened to us with out of warranty Macs before now...

Comment: Thank you I will try that. Maybe they let me buy AppleCare after the warrenty which expired last November.

Comment: Which tests did exactly fail in memtest86? Some test cases might have very rare occurrences in real life. Your problem might not be just RAM, it might be something else. Can you check the installation log and report any specific failure messages?

Answer (score 1):

Tho it is possible in Linux and Mac O/S X is in fact a UNIX-based operating system I am not aware of a way to do this in Mac O/S X.

As for your particular Mac, I believe that the RAM is non replaceable (EG soldered to the system board). So if it is out of warranty and you did not extend the warranty with Applecare a system board replacement would not be cheap.

If you have a local Apple store you can make a Genius appointment and they will diagnose your issue and advise you what can be done at no charge.